# Cloned Disk with dd in Linux Live Image

Tags: linux, clone, dd

I used dd to clone with an Ubuntu Live Image from a smaller SSD to a bigger one. During the cloning process Ubuntu freezed. I waited some time and did a hard shutdown. After rebooting it seems the clone was successful, so I changed UUID and booted from the new clone and everything worked fine. Now I want to reformat the old SSD can I be sure that all the data got copied?

I cloned Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If I used a logfile, the log file will tell you far the dd ran.
If you used the GPT partition scheme you should be able to find a duplicate of the GPT structure at the end of the disk.